# List of JDBC PreparedStatements and Postgres prepared statements

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, mybatis, spring-jdbc

I want to understand RAM usage of our application and postgres DB better, when it comes to prepared statements. In [this article about postgres prepared statements](https://foojay.io/today/a-dissection-of-java-jdbc-to-postgresql-connections/), it is mentioned that JDBC per default only creates a postgres prepared statement once the statement was prepared more than 5 times.

So there is

1. a list in Java that contains all statements ever issued via JDBC and
2. a list in postgres of all prepared statements

To understand the contents of (2) I think I know there is no better way than to select from pg_prepared_statements from the java app and store the result somewhere.

But what do I need to do to understand the content of (1) on my app on production without heap-dumping? What function can I call and write the results to the logs to disect what statements are in the list of JDBC 'prepared statements'**?**

Comment: I don't think you can see that. But if a prepared statements is no longer referenced, the garbage collector will get it eventually, which will also deallocate server side prepared statements.

Comment: Your question conflates JDBC with the PostgreSQL JDBC driver; JDBC is the specification and API, which does nothing on its own. Specific behaviour comes from a driver implementation (like the PostgreSQL JDBC driver). It is the PostgreSQL JDBC driver implementation which tracks this and decides to prepare or not.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes thank you for this insightful comment, I saw in heapdumps that for postgres, the prepared statements seem to sit in objects of kind org.postgresql.core.CachedQuery. Not sure yet though how I can access that information at runtime, without heap dumping.

Comment: A quick look through the pgjdbc sources suggests the execute count is tracked in `CachedQuery`, but the decision to prepare is made in `PgStatement` (in `isOneShotQuery`). However, as far as I can tell, this is not exposed.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel tyvm - I will have to use heap dumping for my analysis then.

Comment: You can use reflection and access that stuff by setting fields etc to accessible. But what help will it be to you to store prepared statements, i don't know. Better create a trace on postgre-side